# Arabic strings generated by gettext are shown scrambled in Qt UI

Tags: python, qt, pyside, arabic

I am working on a multi-language  interface using Qt4 and pyside. Languages works fines on the mainform.

I used 2 ways for localization:

1. Qt tr function for Qt UI files
2. Gettext for python scripts and Jinja2 html templates

When I show Qt dialogs with gettext translated strings, Arabic strings are shown scrambled.

Code that generates the issue:

```
mb = QtGui.QMessageBox(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning, _(u"Applying skin"), _(u"You should restart application in order for the skin to take effect"), buttons = QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
ret = mb.exec_()
```

Comment: Make sure all your source code files are encoded as `utf-8` and put a coding comment at the top of your python modules (e.g. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`). If you're using python3, the coding comment isn't actually needed, because `utf-8` is assumed - but python2 assumes `latin-1`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am using the encoding in the header and other unicode strings are shown well. The only problem is in Qt Dialogues

Comment: @bigOTHER. Are you using `gettext` to translate the strings? How do you expect people to understand your problem when you leave out almost all of the relevant information? Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this myself, but try:

```
gettext.install('myapp', unicode=True)
```

Or if that doesn't work, then try:

```
_ = gettext.translation('myapp').ugettext
```

The problem appears to be that the default in Python2 is for `gettext` to return `bytes` rather than `unicode`.

Comment: I used unicode() to convert one message and it works so its definitely as you said. Though, no one of the two instructions worked for me to force returning unicode as default.

Comment: @bigOTHER. You must be doing something wrong, because for me, the first method definitely sets `_()` to `ugettext` and always returns unicode strings. What is the output when you do `print _` after the `gettext.install` line?

Comment: it works for both, I just needed to specify the localepath:
`gettext.install('myapp', localedir= LOCALPATH, unicode=True)` or `_ = gettext.translation("myapp" , LOCALPATH).ugettext`